# Deploy a Vue.js app on Google Compute Engine

Tags: vue.js, google-compute-engine

I created a simple Vue.js application. I am trying to deploy it on Google compute engine(not app engine or any other), but I can't find any appropriate solution. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployed using express server, Nginx and pm2.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine). It'll be the easiest way to deploy your app without thinking about infrastructure management.

If you really want/need to use [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) you should decide on your own which OS to use and then install and configure all the required software manually.

Meanwhile, I should mention [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) as managed compute platform that automatically scales your stateless containers with your code.

Please update your question if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Serhii. I already created a VM instance in compute engine, install node and uploaded the Vue project.